# Yii front and backend common structure and access to link and htaccess settings

Tags: .htaccess, yii

I m beginner in yii

I have created one structure to handle files for frontend and backend so that common files can be used for both and different files form their folder

---

framework/ (This folder will contain all yii framework core folders and files)
assets/
js/

frontend/

common/

backend/

api

images/
storage/

protected/
components/
config

main.php (DB, emails, etc...)

controllers/

frontend/

backend/

views/

frontend/

backend/

models/
extensions/
modules/

runtime/
index.php
.htaccess

---

this structure is created for booking application.
Some common files are shared between them it will be there in controller/ and views/
and differnrt file will be in controller/frontend/ and controller/backend/

Example
I have files in both folder as below

controller/
SiteController.php

Frontend/SiteController.php

Backend/SiteController.php

views/
layouts/

Frontend/layouts

Backend/layouts

Now the question is how can i set .htaccess so that
when i write http://myapp.com/index.php --> will access all files for frontend
and
http://myapp.com/backend/inex.php --> will access backend files (beckend views and controller)

Answer (score 0):

Copy **.htaccess** and **index.php** to [*/backend/*] folder. Then in new **index.php** change path to the config, different to main one. E.g.

```
$config=dirname(__FILE__).'/../../'.YII_PROTECTED.'/config/admin.production.php';
```

And create own config for the backend independently.

So you can use any common views, controllers or models, but most importantly to control it with UrlManager. Here's an example from [my personal site](http://www.palamarchuk.info) *(you can test its URL logic externally)*:

**Frontend:**

```
    'urlManager'=>array(
        'urlFormat'=>'path',
        'showScriptName'=>false,
        'urlSuffix' => '/',
        'rules'=>array(
            '<controller:profile>/' => '<controller>/index/',
            '<controller:profile>/<action:cv>/<project:\w+>' => '<controller>/portfolio/',
            '<controller:profile>/<action>' => '<controller>/<action>/',
            '<controller:blog>/' => '<controller>/index/',
            '<controller:blog>/<postID:[0-9]+>.html' => '<controller>/post/',
        ),
    ),
```

**Backend:**

```
    'rules'=>array(
        '/' => 'autoadmin/default/index',
        '<controller:\w+>' => 'autoadmin/<controller>/index',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => 'autoadmin/<controller>/<action>',
    ),
```

The Backend looks into [AutoAdmin CMS](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/autoadmin/), which executes as a module.

The both use the same file structure, but each can use anything common (most probably it would be models).